# Recuperar instancia do jQuery dentro de um iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso recuperar a instancia do jQuery incorporado em meu iframe, como sabemos há varias maneiras de recuperar a instancia do jQuery, com as referencias `$`, `jQuery`, `window["$"]`, `window["jQuery"]`.

O problema é que quando tento usar este mesmo método com um iframe o resultado não é o mesmo, segue o código que estou tentando.

```
$("#frame").get(0).contentWindow.window["$"]
```

ou

```
var iframeWindow = $("#frame").get(0).contentWindow; 
console.log( iframeWindow["$"] );
```

> [Demonstração do meu teste](http://jsfiddle.net/p8saa3f0/2/)

Comment: Mister Tuyoshi, poderia melhor explicar a sua dúvida...

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha eu tenho um iframe que possui o jQuery incorporado, preciso recuperar a instancia do jQuery do iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não descurando os potenciais problemas causados pela [politica da mesma-origem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), uma possível solução para o que procuras:

Exemplo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/wgz4x992/).

**HTML**

```html
<iframe id="bubu" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```js
// Conteúdo da iFrame com jQuery incluído e um alert() para vermos que chegou lá
var H = '<html><body><h1 id="hh">JavaScript</h1>';
    H += '<scr' + 'ipt src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';
    H += '<scr' + 'ipt>$(document).ready(function() {';
    H += 'alert("yay");';
    H += '});</scr' + 'ipt>';
    H += '</body></html>';

// apanhar a iFrame
var myIframe = document.getElementById("bubu");

// Escrever o conteúdo que preparamos
var myIframeContent =  myIframe.contentDocument ||  myIframe.contentWindow.document;
myIframeContent.open();
myIframeContent.write(H);
myIframeContent.close();

// Apanhar a janela (window) da iFrame
var myIframeWin = myIframe.contentWindow || myIframe.contentDocument;

// Alguns navegadores não devolvem a Window, tentamos ir busca-la
if (!myIframeWin.document) {
    myIframeWin = myIframeWin.parentNode();
}

// A instancia de jQuery
alert(myIframeWin["$"]);
```

---

**Nota:** Testado apenas em Windows 8.1 a correr Google Chrome.

Comment: +1 Muito bom! Você saberia explicar porque quando o IFrame é populado da forma original da pergunta o browser bloqueia o acesso?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um método para varrer a estrutura do objeto e tentar achar objetos guardados sob a chave `$` e `jQuery`.

**Atenção: aqui demorou uns 30 segundos pra terminar, mas pode ser que ai demore mais.**

A busca possui profundidade máxima de 4 níveis.

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/h3rjnjn7/1/)

Dessa forma, dá pra ver que isso funciona:

```
var iframeWindow = $("#frame").get(0); 
var frame$ = iframeWindow.contentWindow.$;
```

**Nota:** não será possível achar a variável caso o IFrame não seja de mesma origem que o contêiner, pois o browser vai bloqueá-lo caso contrário. Provavelmente se configurar o CORS do servidor para aceitar compartilhar recursos, ai sim será possível, mas neste caso terá de ter controle sobre o servidor que fornece conteúdo do IFrame.

Criar um IFrame vazio na mão, deixando o `src` em branco também fará com que seu acesso às variáveis do IFrame seja bloqueado. Eu testei com o exemplo que você forneceu a principio e não funcionou.

[jsfiddle - provando que assim não funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/p8saa3f0/5/)

Comment: Muito obrigado ótima explicação, eu não sabia que mesmo ao deixar o SRC vazio ainda sim eu estava violando a politica da mesma-origem, O que me deixa intrigado é por que o exemplo feito pelo @Zuul funciona com SRC em branco.